# Calculating pi using BigDecimals and the Nilakantha series does not work for more than 10 decimal places

Tags: java, loops, bigdecimal, pi

Here's my code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Challenge6 {

    private static final String PI = "3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756482337867831652712019091456485669234603486104543266482133936072602491412737245870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919530921861173819326117931051185480744623799627495673518857527248912279381830119491298336733624406566430860213949463952247371907021798609437027705392171762931767523846748184676694051320005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301465495853710507922796892589235420199561121290219608640344181598136297747713099605187072113499999983729780499510597317328160963185950244594553469083026425223082533446850352619311881710100031378387528865875332083814206171776691473035982534904287554687311595628638823537875937519577818577805321712268066130019278766111959092164201989380952572010654858632788659361533818279682303019520353018529689957736225994138912497217752834791315155748572424541506959508295";

    public static BigDecimal calculatePi(int decimals) {

        BigDecimal pi = new BigDecimal(3);
        boolean toggle = true;
        boolean enough = false;
        int i = 2;

        while (!enough) {
            BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(
                    (double) (4 / (double) (i * (i + 1) * (i + 2))));
            System.out.println(i / 2);

            if (toggle) {
                pi = pi.add(num);
                toggle = false;

            } else {
                pi = pi.subtract(num);
                toggle = true;
            }
            i += 2;

            try {
                if (PI.substring(0, decimals + 2).equals(
                        ("" + pi).substring(0, decimals + 2))) {
                    enough = true;
                } else {

                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return pi;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Pi: %.30s", calculatePi(10));
    }
}
```

I know it's not perfect, but it's just for fun. I'm just wondering why my program can perfectly generate pi up to 10 decimal places in just over 700 iterations, but when I try to calculate any more than 10, it goes forever (at least I assume forever). Is this just due to floating point division or something? If so, why does it just *stop* working right after 10? Also, if you run the program while printing out pi every iteration, it turns to something like 3.39. Is BigDecimal having issues here, or is there something wrong with my code? Any help would be cool.

P.S. - I only really need 30 decimal places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use expression "new BigDecimal( (double) (4 / (double) (i * (i + 1) * (i + 2))))" you use double, not BigDecimal. And using double ins't posible to have sufficient scale for callculation more then 10 decimal places.

Use following code

```
public static BigDecimal calculatePi(int decimals) {
    BigDecimal pi = new BigDecimal(3);
    boolean toggle = true;
    boolean enough = false;
    int i = 2;

    while (!enough) {
        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(4); // All operation must be using only BigDecimal 
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(i).multiply(new BigDecimal(i + 1)).multiply(new BigDecimal(i + 2));
        BigDecimal num = a.divide(b, 100, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        System.out.println(i / 2);

        if (toggle) {
            pi = pi.add(num);
            toggle = false;

        } else {
            pi = pi.subtract(num);
            toggle = true;
        }
        i += 2;

        if (PI.substring(0, decimals + 2).equals(("" + pi).substring(0, decimals + 2))) {
            enough = true;
        }
    }
    return pi;
}
```

**P.S.** I check this code for 20 decimal places, but for 30 decimal places you need waiting a lot of time, I think

Comment: Thanks! Looks like my problem was definitely just that I had to make everything BigDecimal. Any idea why my old code stopped working after 10 decimal places, though?

Comment: It isnt't stop, it's working forever, but in expression "new BigDecimal( (double) (4 / (double) (i * (i + 1) * (i + 2))))" you use double, not BigDecimal. And using double ins't  posible to have sufficient scale.

Comment: Right, but it does calculate pi to 10 decimal places, but it does not calculate pi accurately after 11.

Comment: Yes, double enough to 10 decimal places, but not for 11 decimal places

Comment: This would be a much better answer if your first comment were part of the answer.  Currently, the answer doesn't explain why it addresses the problem.

Comment: Add comment to answer

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using the BigDecimal class does nothing.  The divide as a double (and the accuracy of the denominator as it gets big) will be your limiting factors.

Try doing all those operations using BigDecimal components that use the BigDecimal operations for the division--and you probably want to use BigDecimal components in the denominator as well.

Actually you could make the denominator into a long and just use a single BigNum divide operation until the long overflows.  I recommend not using a Double or anything else for the denominator because you will have trouble detecting a loss of precision.